# Excel clearing corresponding cells from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have built a tool that uses a userform to populate "Worksheet3" in my workbook with information input by the user. My issue is that while I am debugging and testing, I manually clear the data in "Worksheet3" to retest how it is working by highlighting  the data in that sheet and press "delete" and this does not delete the data in WS3 , but rather the corresponding cells in "Worksheet1" which contain my cell links for the controls in my userform. How do I prevent this from happening? I have already tried writing code to specify that the focus is on WS3 to ensure that when I close the userform I can clear just the cells in the correct worksheet. Anyone else ever run into this problem?

Comment: Are you using `Applicaiton.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: I was, but I also had a `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end of that code, but I removed them both and it seems to be working okay now. Are there any other things that could cause that type of problem?

Comment: nope :) No need to remove them both. Just before you try to delete the cells,  switch it back on from the immediate window :)

Comment: Yeah thats what I was afraid of, I deleted any lines that had to do with screen updating to see if maybe one of them was causing my issue, but now I am running into other problems where actions are meshing across worksheets. :/

Comment: You do not have to delete any lines... Like I said, Just before you try to delete the cells manually, switch `Application.ScreenUpdating` back on from the immediate window :)